# How can I group dictionary by key that is List(Of Object)?

Tags: .net, linq, list, dictionary

I have `Dictionary(Of List(Of Object), Integer)` and need to get my dictionary grouped by keys.

For example:

```
Dictionary (0) = Key: {List(12, "SomeString", 3)} Value: 54

Dictionary (1) = Key: {List(8, "SomeAnotherString", 3)} Value: 6

Dictionary (2) = Key: {List(12, "SomeString", 3)} Value: 15
```

How can I get this `Dictionary` looks like:

```
Dictionary (0) = Key: {List(12, "SomeString", 3)} Value: 54, 15

Dictionary (1) = Key: {List(8, "SomeAnotherString", 3)} Value: 6
```

Comment: What's the point of having a dictionary with keys that do not produce a proper hash code, and have no equality checker? Another point is that the dictionary cannot have multiple items per key.

Comment: Values: 54, 15 can be a `List(of integer)`.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight said, having list as key is almost certainly not what you want. Perhaps you expect something like this: [12] => 54, 15 ; "SomeString" => 54, 15; 8 => 6?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a solution in C# but converting it into VB.NET should not be a problem for you.

Also I am assuming that the number of objects present in the List(of object) is always 3 and in the order of type int, string, int.

The following is my solution to your problem.

1. Create a new class say "MyList" which inherits from List(of object)
2. Override Equals method in "MyList" class and in that method check if the passed list is same as the current list by checking each element
3. Create the original dictionary as key = "MyList", value = int
4. Create a new dictionary as key = "MyList", value = List(of int)
5. Create a method which will call the overriden equals method and adds a new key/value if returned false and adds the value to that key if returned true

The following is the entire code

```
    Dictionary<MyList, List<int>> newOtherDict;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Dummy data for testing
        Dictionary<MyList, int> myDict = new Dictionary<MyList, int>();
        myDict.Add(new MyList() {1, "SomeString", 3 }, 1);
        myDict.Add(new MyList() { 1, "SomeOtherString", 3 }, 12);
        myDict.Add(new MyList() { 1, "SomeString", 3 }, 123);

        //This dictionary will contain the consolidated values
        newOtherDict = new Dictionary<MyList, List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myDict.Count; i++)
        {
            AddOrAppendToNewDict(myDict.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }

    private void AddOrAppendToNewDict(KeyValuePair<MyList, int> keyValue)
    {
        var foundPair = newOtherDict.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(keyValue.Key));

        if (foundPair.Count() == 0)
        {
            newOtherDict.Add(keyValue.Key, new List<int>() { keyValue.Value });
        }
        else
        {
            foundPair.First().Value.Add(keyValue.Value);
        }
    }

    class MyList : List<object>
    {
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            List<object> toCompareClass = obj as List<object>;

            if (Convert.ToInt32(this[0]) == Convert.ToInt32(toCompareClass[0]) &&
                Convert.ToInt32(this[2]) == Convert.ToInt32(toCompareClass[2]) &&
                this[1].ToString() == toCompareClass[1].ToString())
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Regards,

Samar

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how dictionaries work.
The values of a dictionary are accessed by their unique keys. Internally they are looked up using the hash codes produced by the keys. To work properly the hash codes require a few properties:

- Two objects that compare as equal must have identical hash codes.
- If a mutable object produces a hash code that relies on its mutable state it should not be used as a key in a dictionary. The reason is simple: If you put such an object into a hash table and mutate it you will not be able to find it again.

The hash codes are produced by the [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) function that might be overriden by any type. 
You use `List(Of Object)` as key values. `List(Of Object)` does not override `GetHashCode`. It uses the default implementation of the Object type. Although this implementation meets the stated requirements it is definitely not what you are looking for.

I noticed that the lists you try to use as keys always have the same structure: an integer, a string and another integer. `List(Of Object)` is not a good choice for keys. But maybe you can create a type that can be used as a key:

```
Public Class MyKey
    Private ReadOnly _firstValue As Integer
    Private ReadOnly _secondValue As String
    Private ReadOnly _thirdValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(firstValue As Integer, secondValue As String, thirdValue As Integer)
        _firstValue = firstValue
        _secondValue = secondValue
        _thirdValue = thirdValue
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property FirstValue As Integer
        Get
            Return _firstValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property SecondValue As String
        Get
            Return _secondValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ThirdValue As Integer
        Get
            Return _thirdValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim hashCode As Integer = 31
        hashCode = hashCode + 17 * _firstValue
        hashCode = hashCode + 17 * _secondValue.GetHashCode()
        hashCode = hashCode + 17 * _thirdValue

        Return hashCode
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If TypeOf obj Is MyKey Then
            Dim other As MyKey = CType(obj, MyKey)
            Return _firstValue = other._firstValue And
                   _secondValue = other._secondValue And
                   _thirdValue = other._thirdValue
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

This type can be used for dictionary keys. It produces a proper hash code and overrides [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) to compare the contents instead of the references. Also it is immutable to ensure that the hash code never changes.

Dictionaries require unique keys. Since your keys aren't unique the values need to be of type List(Of Integer). Adding a value requires some extra work. First you have to check if the key already exists in the dictionary. If not create a new entry:

```
Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of MyKey, List(Of Integer))
Add(dictionary, New MyKey(12, "SomeString", 3), 54)
Add(dictionary, New MyKey(8, "SomeAnotherString", 3), 6)
Add(dictionary, New MyKey(12, "SomeString", 3), 15)

Public Sub Add(dictionary As Dictionary(Of MyKey, List(Of Integer)), key As MyKey, value As Integer)
    Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
    If Not dictionary.TryGetValue(key, list) Then
        list = New List(Of Integer)()
        dictionary.Add(key, list)
    End If

    list.Add(value)
End Sub
```